# xml delete element by counting not attribute

Tags: xml

Hi I have an extra large xml file (40+ GB). The simplified structure is

```
<xml>
    <element>111</element>
    <element>222</element>
    <element>333</element>
    <element>444</element>
    <element>555</element>
    <element>666</element>
    ...
</xml>
```

and I'm trying to delete number 2,000,000 element and I do not know the content of the element. Is there a way for me to do so? Having been searching for hours but only found xml query based on attributes. Thanks!

Comment: With what language are you trying to delete this node?

Comment: Actually any language or tools would be appreciated as long as it serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on UNIX and the file is known to be always in that format, it is probably easiest to use `sed`.

```
sed -e '2000001d' infile > outfile
```

If you need to parse the actual XML structure, you could consider `xml-sed`.

Comment: Thanks. That did delete on tag but there is a problem. Inside <element> there is also attributes and your suggestion only counts the tags but not distinguish different layers. So actually it would be deleting the 2000000 tag but not the 2000000 <element>. What should I do to get the 2000000 element?

Comment: Do you have (or can you install) xml-sed?

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to delete the first five `element`s. First, get the line of the first opening `<element>`.

```
$ opening=$(grep -n '<element>' < x.xml | head -1 | cut -d: -f1)
```

Then get the line of the fifth closing `</element>`.

```
$ closing=$(grep -n '</element>' < x.xml | head -n5 | tail -1 | cut -d: -f1)
```

Now delete the lines from `opening` to `closing`.

```
$ sed "${opening},${closing}d" < x.xml
```

Output:

```
<xml>
    <element>666</element>
</xml>
```

If you are unsure of the format of the XML file, use `xmllint` to clean it.

```
$ xmllint -format x.xml
```